# PDO fetch fixed number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I can't concurrently fetch all 300k rows due to memory limit.
Any way to cycle in predefined chunks using while/fetch of PDO?
Something like:

```
while($result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, N))
```

Where N is a predefined interval.

Comment: use limit and offset in your query

Answer (score 3):

You don't need that. Your memory issue is caused by the [unbuffered query](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#mysqlnd)

So, just add this magic line before your query

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, FALSE);
```

and have not a single problem with memory anymore - your code

```
while($result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

will ocupy no more than single row worth of RAM

Comment: This way I'm fetching one result per cycle...I need to fetch all results in an array.

Comment: That's strange. what's the use of a partial array? I can't get it. Either you need all 300k rows in a single array, or just iterate one by one.